# Reputation behind my user name not the same as the list in the reputation tab on the user page

Tags: support, reputation

Hi, on the StackOverflow I have a current reputation of 131.

However if I look at the reputation tab in the user screen ([Edelcom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231181/edelcom)), and add them together :

> 55  How am I supposed to use JEDI’s JCLCompression to create a 7z archive?
>   20  FastShareMem still necessary in Delphi-2010?
>   20  Profiler able to start profiling when executing some procedure
>   10  IE6 problem with dynamically adjusting the height of a div
>   10  What is a good library for creating PDFs in Delphi 2010?
>   10  ASP Round function not behaving as expected
>   -2  Why can’t I add small comments to questions

I count 123 points.

Where does the difference come from ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get two points for every answer you've accepted. You've accepted four of them and that makes the difference of eight points.

Here's the entire breakdown:

> 55 How am I supposed to use JEDI’s JCLCompression to create a 7z archive?
>   20 FastShareMem still necessary in Delphi-2010?
>   20 Profiler able to start profiling when executing some procedure
>   10 IE6 problem with dynamically adjusting the height of a div
>   10 What is a good library for creating PDFs in Delphi 2010?
>   10 ASP Round function not behaving as expected
>   -2 Why can’t I add small comments to questions
>   1 (original 1 rep)
>   -1 (a downvote you've given)
>   8 (4 accepted answers at 2 points each)

That adds up to 131.

Comment: Thank you. I did read the FAQ of Stack Overflow but found nothing about the 2 points/accepted answers. Can you tell me also, why I recieved 55 points for the first item in the list ? I did 4 upvotes, do you get 15 points when the answer is accepted ?

Comment: Yep, 15 rep when an answer is accepted.